# Omnifunction mode in japanese

Tags: neovim

In my nvim editor, when I make the omnicompletion, informations of mode are wrtiten in japanese

instead of english. [my nvim screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ueLc.jpg)

I tried to uninstall and install again but nothing happen.

I don't know how change back this message in english.